# StackPanel with huge amount of children

Tags: wpf, performance, wpf-controls, stackpanel

i'm building a wpf control based on the outlook calender sample in code project,

first of all i wanna know if this is a good sample or that this is not the way of writing controls?

second, i need to support milliseconds view of the calender, the meaning of that is 
**more than 24 * 60 * 60 items**

my question is how to build this panel(if it should still be a `StackPanel`)
and how can i refill the panel when resolution (zoom) changes and avoid stucking the gui while i perform the fill.

to sum up : i need a fast way to insert many items to a `StackPanel` in wpf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the [`VirtualizingStackPanel` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx). Remember you need to databind the items of the panel to make it virtual.

Comment: Indeed, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do [UI Virtualization](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=338) to do this; although, I'm not sure what the usability ramifications of having 80k rows would be.